# Postgres COPY with multiple small chunks

Tags: postgresql, copy

In postgres, we can do COPY to export the data into file. But all the data will be saved into a file. But I want to chunk that file into small files. We can do this after the export.

But is there a way to export it during the COPY process?

OR in psycopg2 can we do this?

Comment: You could provide the table DDL so that an optimal field can be chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `WHERE` condition:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM tab WHERE id % 3 = 0) TO '/dir/file1.csv' (FORMAT 'csv');
COPY (SELECT * FROM tab WHERE id % 3 = 1) TO '/dir/file2.csv' (FORMAT 'csv');
COPY (SELECT * FROM tab WHERE id % 3 = 2) TO '/dir/file3.csv' (FORMAT 'csv');
```

Here `id` stands for any numerical column. You can also use other data types and split up the data in other ways with an appropriate `WHERE` condition.

Comment: `WHERE id % 3 = 0` will this work only if i have the id column?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: in the where condition you mentioned that `id`, if I don't have this column in the table, then it wont run right?

Comment: Ah, I see. I have added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> But is there a way to export it during the COPY process?

Streaming the COPY data into a program is supported through the `PROGRAM` clause.

The Unix command [`split`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) can do the actual splitting. For instance:

```
COPY (<your query>) TO PROGRAM 'split -l 10000 -d - /path/file-';
```

This will split the output into files numbered sequentially that do not exceed 10000 lines each.

The `PROGRAM` clause is also supported by psql's `\copy`; in that case the program is executed client-side.

Caveat: if the export format is CSV and there are multi-line text fields, it comes with the risk of splitting a field across multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a big file and have enough disc space you can use the method below.

Suppose that you have created a big file with copy command;

```
COPY (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...) TO '/path/to/file';
```

Split files into chunks (Linux only);

```
split --number=l/10 --numeric-suffixes /path/to/file file_
```